# django 1.10 custom user model and user manager

Tags: python, django

Im trying to create a custom user model and his manager

[gist with code](https://gist.github.com/bitgandtter/9fc0de497a3cc13440e24a86ba6626b1)

But for some reason when y try to create a user with the

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

It rise an error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'jmessages_customer.last_login' in 'field list'")
```

Its like its not using my custom manager at the moment

Comment: Check this line: ```class Customer(AbstractBaseUser):``` then name sure you have run ```python manage.py makemigrations``` and ```python manage.py migrate```

Comment: hey @luke_aus the migrations where run and all ran just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solition was to specify the missing property on the model

```
last_login = None
```

the same as

```
is_active = True
```

In deed those need to be correctly handled in the future but at list this issue was fixed.

Comment: Something looks wrong with your setup. Django has already defined both of these in AbstractBaseUser - check out the code https://github.com/django/django/blob/39805686b364358af725b695924a5a6dfa7f5302/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L52

Comment: have you got in your settings: AUTH_USER_MODEL = "jmessages.Customer"

Comment: @luke_aus indeed but for some reason is not working, the only way was to re-define it on my class